# Show that $e^{X^2/2} \in L^1$ iff $e^{XY} \in L^1$ iff $e^{|XY|} \in L^1$

Tags: probability-theory, lp-spaces, expected-value

let $X, Y$ be two identically distributed (both are $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$) independent random variables

show that $e^{\frac{X^2}{2}} \in L^1 \iff e^{XY} \in L^1 \iff e^{|XY|} \in L^1$.

my attempt :

1st equivalence :

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[e^{XY}] &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{xy}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dydx =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{xy-\frac{y^2}{2}}dydx \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2}}dydx \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}dudx \\
& = \mathbb{E}[e^{\frac{X^2}{2}}]
\end{align} $$

I mean yeah this kinda proves that $e^{\frac{X^2}{2}} \in L^1 \iff e^{XY} \in L^1 $

but something is bothering me,

because $\mathbb{E}[e^{\frac{X^2}{2}}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}dx = +\infty$

**Q1** :

> can't we just say that $e^{\frac{X^2}{2}} \in L^1$ is a false claim therefore it can imply anything we desire ?

second equivalence : from the fact that $0< e^{XY} \leq e^{|XY|}$

we conclude that $ e^{|XY|} \in L^1 \implies e^{XY} \in L^1$

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[e^{|XY|}] &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{|xy|}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dydx \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}(\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{|xy|}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy +\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{|xy|}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy)dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}[\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}(\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{xy}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy +\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-xy}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy)dx +\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}(\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xy}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy +\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{xy}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy)dx]\\
& \leq \text{Constant}[\mathbb{E}[e^{XY}] + \mathbb{E}[e^{-XY}] ] = \text{Constant}_2[\mathbb{E}[e^{XY}]] 
\end{align} $$

I used the fact that $-X$ and $Y$ are independant and that $X = -X\, \text{in distribution}$

**Q2** :

> was my attempt at proving 2nd equivalence correct ?

thanks !

edit 1 : pic of the original problem (it's in french) [image: see comment section below for translation]

Comment: Are you sure you were asked to prove these (rather odd) equivalences, or did you make them up yourself, to solve another problem?

Comment: @Did here is a pic (https://imgur.com/a/5AgV1c8) of the problem, it's from an exam.

calculer means 'compute', montrer que means 'show that', sans means 'without' and $M_x$ here denotes the moment generating function

Comment: "Click below to consent to the use of this technology across the web" No thanks.

Comment: @Did link is messy ? I added the pic to my post for more convenience.

Comment: Hmmm... Actually the whole exercise is wrong since, the random variable $e^{XY}$ failing to be integrable, the conditional expectation $E(e^{XY}\mid X)$ does not exist.

Comment: What is the source of the exercise?

Comment: @Did my teacher said he saw it in the following book : https://www.amazon.fr/Exercices-probabilit%C3%A9s-Licence-Master-ding%C3%A9nieurs/dp/2842251563

Comment: @mathex Not a book by Ouvrard.

Comment: In Ouvrard the question is more general

Comment: @mathex I happen to have Ouvrard's book, could you point me out the number of the page and which 'tome'?

Comment: it's tome 2 exercise 11.6 page 177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[e^{XY}|X]$ exists since $0 \leq e^{XY}$ (it's an extension from $L^2$ to non negative variables!!)

Let's suppose that we don't know the distribution of $X$. And suppose that $E[e^{\frac{X^2}{2}}]<+\infty$

Observe that:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{|xy|}e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2}dy)dP_X(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\int_{]0;+\infty[}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y-|x|)^2}dy)dP_X(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\int_{]-|x|;+\infty[}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2}du)dP_X(x) \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2}du)dP_X(x) \leq 2E[e^{\frac{X^2}{2}}]<+\infty$$

And then the equivalence!! (the exercise is true if the distribution of $X$ is unknown)

Comment: great detail concerning the distribution of $X$

Comment: From where did you bring the exercise?

Comment: We don't need to know the distribution of X. So the exercise is true!

Comment: it's from an exam, the teacher said he found it in this book : https://www.amazon.fr/Exercices-probabilit%C3%A9s-Licence-Master-ding%C3%A9nieurs/dp/2842251563